# Get surface size in Fragment Shader (GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm writing a shader for my mesh that has triangles of different sizes, in 3 dimensions. Therefore if I "blur" or feather in my fragment stage, I get the same amount of blur, despite the size of the triangle I'm fragmenting. Some triangles are huge, some are tiny.

I want to have a reference value to get a right proportion of my triangle.

Is there a way to get the length of the triangle, so that I have a scale beside my UV coords.

Please find this image to show what I mean: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzXOZ.jpg) . I want to get the result of #3

I'm working in OpenGL, GLSL.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered using dfdx and dfdy (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml)? With that you can check how much the current fragment is distant from the adjacent fragments and so you can get a measurement of how much you have "walked" inside the triangle.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really need a value to follow the proportion of the area of the triangle or the length of the edge in which the vertex sits in regards to the next vertex (in CW or CCW order), you could add a vertex attribute and pre-compute those on CPU before sending the triangles to the GPU.

Comment: Can't really figure out how to start with DFDX.... your second option is the way in the end I think...

Comment: I think you could possibly compute those values in the geometry shader, but if your mesh is static and if you can precompute those values before sending them to the GPU, I guess that'd be better.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a Geometry shader.